# CSS rotate animation of HTML circle text, transform-origin doesn't work

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have a problem in applying CSS *transform:rotate* animation to a circle text obtained in HTML.

```css
.rotText{
  min-width: 80vw;
  margin: 5vh auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
#test{
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #394add;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 128px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  transform: scale(1);
  transform-origin: center center;
  animation: rotation 5s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes rotation {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="rotText">
<img src="05-img/Thinking man.png" alt="">
  <div class="curved-text" id="test">
    <p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(0deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%">c</p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(8.78048780487805deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%">o</p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(17.5609756097561deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%">l</p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(26.34146341463415deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%">l</p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(35.1219512195122deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%">e</p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(43.90243902439025deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%">g</p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(52.6829268292683deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%">a</p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(61.463414634146346deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%">r</p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(70.2439024390244deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%">e</p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(79.02439024390245deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%"> </p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(87.8048780487805deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%">i</p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(96.58536585365854deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%">l</p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(105.3658536585366deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%"> </p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(114.14634146341464deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%">c</p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(122.92682926829269deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%">e</p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(131.70731707317074deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%">r</p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(140.4878048780488deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%">v</p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(149.26829268292684deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%">e</p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(158.0487804878049deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%">l</p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(166.82926829268294deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%">l</p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(175.609756097561deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%">o</p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(184.39024390243904deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%"> </p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(193.1707317073171deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%">p</p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(201.95121951219514deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%">r</p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(210.7317073170732deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%">i</p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(219.51219512195124deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%">m</p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(228.2926829268293deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%">a</p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(237.07317073170734deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%"> </p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(245.85365853658539deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%">d</p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(254.63414634146343deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%">i</p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(263.4146341463415deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%"> </p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(272.19512195121956deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%">p</p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(280.9756097560976deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%">r</p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(289.7560975609756deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%">o</p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(298.5365853658536deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%">c</p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(307.31707317073165deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%">e</p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(316.09756097560967deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%">d</p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(324.8780487804877deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%">e</p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(333.6585365853657deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%">r</p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(342.43902439024373deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%">e</p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(351.21951219512175deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%"></p>
</div>
</div>
```

So, the *rotation keyframe* works correctly, but I really can't move the origin of the DIV (class 'curved-text'). Is there someone who's able to explain me where is the problem?

I supposed it could be due to the external DIV's origin, so I tried to change it with CSS command, but it didn't work.

Any idea?

Comment: What happens when you give ```#test``` a height value: ```height: calc(330px + 2rem);```.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Giving height to the parent of your absolute positioned children, this what you are looking for?

```css
.rotText{
  min-width: 80vw;
  margin: 5vh auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
#test{
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #394add;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 128px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  transform: scale(1);
  transform-origin: center center;
  animation: rotation 5s linear infinite;
  height: calc(330px + 2rem);.
}
@keyframes rotation {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="rotText">
<img src="05-img/Thinking man.png" alt="">
  <div class="curved-text" id="test">
    <p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(0deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%">c</p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(8.78048780487805deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%">o</p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(17.5609756097561deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%">l</p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(26.34146341463415deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%">l</p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(35.1219512195122deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%">e</p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(43.90243902439025deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%">g</p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(52.6829268292683deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%">a</p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(61.463414634146346deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%">r</p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(70.2439024390244deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%">e</p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(79.02439024390245deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%"> </p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(87.8048780487805deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%">i</p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(96.58536585365854deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%">l</p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(105.3658536585366deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%"> </p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(114.14634146341464deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%">c</p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(122.92682926829269deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%">e</p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(131.70731707317074deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%">r</p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(140.4878048780488deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%">v</p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(149.26829268292684deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%">e</p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(158.0487804878049deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%">l</p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(166.82926829268294deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%">l</p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(175.609756097561deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%">o</p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(184.39024390243904deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%"> </p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(193.1707317073171deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%">p</p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(201.95121951219514deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%">r</p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(210.7317073170732deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%">i</p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(219.51219512195124deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%">m</p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(228.2926829268293deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%">a</p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(237.07317073170734deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%"> </p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(245.85365853658539deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%">d</p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(254.63414634146343deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%">i</p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(263.4146341463415deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%"> </p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(272.19512195121956deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%">p</p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(280.9756097560976deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%">r</p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(289.7560975609756deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%">o</p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(298.5365853658536deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%">c</p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(307.31707317073165deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%">e</p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(316.09756097560967deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%">d</p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(324.8780487804877deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%">e</p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(333.6585365853657deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%">r</p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(342.43902439024373deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%">e</p><p style="height:165px; position:absolute; transform:rotate(351.21951219512175deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%"></p>
</div>
</div>
```